# Using a pList to Update Core Data

Tags: core-data, plist

Can use a little guidance here. I get a daily update of a 15,000+ record database in XML format. This is the source data for my app in which I am using Core Data. The contents of the XML dump changes on a daily basis in the following ways:
1) Some records will be deleted.
2) New records will be added.
3) Existing records may be modified.

What is the best way to update Core Data with the daily changes from this XML file? My thinking is that I am going to have to iterate through the pList and somehow compare that to what is already in Core Data. Not sure how to do this.

I did a search on the site and found this article but not sure if this is what I need to do: [Initialize Core Data With Default Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269385/initialize-core-data-with-default-data)

Thank you in advance.
Darin

Comment: Are the records easy to compare (with UIDs or the like)?

Comment: Each record does have a unique 6 digit pin number.

Comment: How big is your total database? What fraction of it changes each day? Is the XML format under your control? Do you have a server that's under your control that can manipulate the data? Is the XML to Core Data conversion done on an iOS device, or a Mac?

Comment: Do you really need to update your existing store or can you just replace it entirely with the new data?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say specifically, but I'm guessing that your total database size is 15,000+ records, and that your XML update contains values for all of them. Here are some ideas to consider.

Do the XML records contain a date of last modification? If not, can you add that? Then note the last time your Core Data version was updated, and ignore all XML records older than that.

For the records that are deleted, you'll have to find them in Core Data and then delete them. You'll probably see better performance if you set your fetch request's result type to `NSManagedObjectIDResultType`. The NSPersistentObjects don't need to be fully realized in order to delete them.

If you're stuck with undated XML, try adding an entity just for change detection. Store the 6 digit pin number, and the `-hash` of the entire original XML string for the relevant record. Upon update, fetch the pin/hash pair and compare. If the hash values are the same, it's unlikely that the data has changed.

This is going to turn into an optimization problem. The best way to proceed will depend on the characteristics of your data: number of attributes, size of records, size of the delta in each daily update. Structure your fetch request predicates to minimize the number of fetch requests you perform (for instance, by using "IN" operator to pass multiple 6-digit pin numbers). Consider using `NSDictionaryResultType` if there's just one attribute you need. Measure first, optimize second.

Comment: Hal. Thank you for this! Just to give you a little more information, I do not have access to the XML file to add additional fields for convenience. The file is a dump from the HR system that contains employee contact information (name, address location etc). There will be adds and deletes on a daily basis but probably not as many changes to existing records. I love your idea about the -hash. While I have never coded something like that before and am not sure how to do it, I understand the logic and can see how it would work.